# Change color-theme in whole iOS application

Tags: ios, runtime, stylesheet

I am going to implement Alert feature in my application.

When user taps an alert button my application is about to change all orange (default) colors to red (Navigation bar, switches, Tab bar, Buttons, views and other stuff).

I want to implement it using "css" files also known as stylesheets.
I've found two libraries: [Motif](https://github.com/erichoracek/motif) and [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui).

The most important problem is to dynamically change theme inside application. Motif can do this but I want to do it more simple.

Also I learned that NUI can change the app theme too but I can't to change it dynamically.

P.S. I am using storyboard and XIB-files. I need to add runtime attribute  for object's key-path. This attribute will go to my stylesheet file and apply styles. It's the most simple way I think.

Can I do it simply and without any libraries?

P.S.S. NUI is more simple for me. Maybe you know how to change styles when application runs.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of making this work, but not very simply. So your options are either to construct your own solution, or use a library.

If you are looking for something that feels easier and more native than NUI or Motif, and which also lets you assign styles and see them rendered live inside your storyboards, take a look at my library for this:  https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish

Here is a demonstration of changing the "stylesheet" (which can be created either in code, or in an external JSON file) at runtime:

[image: Changing Stylesheets at Runtime]